# nuemro +=1, no suma

Tags: python

¿Alguien sabe por qué no suma?

```
from pynput import mouse
import pyautogui
from time import sleep

celdas = 0

def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    if pressed:
        celdas = 0
        ff = (str(button)+" pressed")
        print(str(button)+" pressed")
        celdas +=1
        print(celdas)
        if celdas == 4:
            print("Ya va a ejecutarse")
            sleep(2)
            pyautogui.click()
            celdas = 0
            print(celdas)
 
print(celdas)

with mouse.Listener(
    on_click=on_click
) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Comment: Buen día, dentro de tu `if` estás asignando `celdas = 0` por segunda vez, cada que entras al `if` entonces `celdas` es `0` nuevamente

Answer (score 0):

#### Variables globales vs locales

La variable `celdas` es una variable global (está declarada fuera de toda función).

Dentro de una función, el significado de `celdas` depende del uso:

- Si sólo la consultas, `celdas` es la variable global.
- Si la modificas, `celdas` es una variable local, que se  crea dentro de la función y desaparece al salir de ella.

Dentro de la función `on_click` la variable `celdas` es **local**, y no es la misma variable global anterior.

Para indicar que estás trabajando con la variable global dentro de la función, primero tienes que especificarlo usando la declaración `global`:

```
def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    global celdas
```

#### Lógica

Por otra parte, hay un problema de lógica, que persiste incluso si declaras global la variable.

Examinemos que pasa con la variable `celdas`, eliminando las instrucciones que no la afectan (así es más fácil entenderlo):

```
def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    if pressed:
        celdas = 0           # Vale cero
        celdas += 1          # Vale 1
        if celdas == 4:      # Nunca valdrá cuatro
            celdas = 0       # Nunca se ejecutara.
        # Al llegar acá, celdas vale 1.
```

En resumen, el código se reduce a

```
def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    if pressed:
        celdas = 1
```

#### Solución

Una posible reescritura del código es

```
def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    global celdas
    
    if pressed:
        ff = (str(button)+" pressed")
        print(str(button)+" pressed")
        celdas +=1
        print(celdas)
        if celdas == 4:
            print("Ya va a ejecutarse")
            sleep(2)
            pyautogui.click()
            celdas = 0
            print(celdas)
```

Espero te sea útil.